# Why using constraint layout, a listView pushes button out of screen? how to solve it?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-xml, android-constraintlayout

I have an editText, a button and a listView in a constraint layout.

The problem is that the listView pushes button and editText out of screen when I fill it in.

Can someone help me to solve it, please? Thanks a lot

Here the XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvJugadores"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </ListView>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etJugador"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/etJugadorHint"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lvJugadores" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnConfirmarNuevoJugador"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btnConfirmarNuevoJugador"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etJugador" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Add app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/etJugador" to your ListView tag. And remember don't use match_parent if you are using ConstraintLayout as a parent. If you are using ConstraintLayout as a parent then use 0dp instead of match_parent.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helps me to understand and solve the problem. Good advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvJugadores"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/etJugador">

    </ListView>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etJugador"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="etJugadorHint"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/btnConfirmarNuevoJugador"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"

        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lvJugadores" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnConfirmarNuevoJugador"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="btnConfirmarNuevoJugador"
         app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etJugador"

          //this attribute make button and textview always within screen
          app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Great answer. Thanks a lot. I solved the problem copying and pasting that code. It helped me to understand the problem and improve my knowledge.

Comment: You are welcome!if it is correct, Accept as correct answer .@Javierungo

Answer (score 0):

The problem is as follows. Let us see your code.

```xml
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvJugadores"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </ListView>
```

The height as you can see is `0dp` and there is no `bottom` constraint. There is a top one and start, end ones, but since there is no bottom and the height is `0dp` so it overlays over other.

Now coming onto the solution there can be various solutions to this. I would suggest you chain your `EditText` and `Button` from the bottom and then let the `ListView` take whatever space is remaining.

So your structure would be somewhat like this

- Button constrained to the bottom of parent.
- Edit Text constrained top to bottom of button.
- ListView constrained top to bottom of button and top to top of parent with its height `0dp` thus occupying whatever space available.

Some other solutions can be to give a fixed height of sorts to the `ListView`. For which you can use the `height_percent` attribute and give it something like let us say 70% of screen so it will be `0.7`.

Comment: Great answer. Very complete and useful. Thanks a lot. It helps to learn and understand the problem.